# Do Ashkenazi Jews have the highest IQ in the world?

Tags: intelligence, jews

It is often claimed that Ashkenazi Jews in the U.S. and the UK are the smartest ethnic group in the world:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016028960600033X

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0191886903000795

http://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-4098351,00.html

http://www.israelnationalnews.com/News/News.aspx/131053

http://harpending.humanevo.utah.edu/Documents/ashkiq.webpub.pdf

Is this true?

Comment: @Sancho The first two say that they are smarter (on average) that white gentiles. The headlines of the next two say, `Ashkenazi Jews rank smartest in world` and `Study: Ashkenazi Jews Smartest on Earth, Partly Due to Diseases`.

Comment: @Sancho you removed the "Race" tag claiming that it isn't a question about race. If this just asked about Jews in general, you would probably be right, but Ashkenazim are a fairly genetically distinct group. Sephardim and Ashkenazim are "races" for any reasonable definition of something as squishy as "race". I say this an atheist of Ashkenazic decent.

Comment: @WilliamGrobman Okay, I'm fine if it gets added back. I guess I presumed too much when I deleted it.

Comment: Correct, yes they do.

Comment: why did you delete like half of the post without any reason sancho?